# Type error when calling mapped action - mapping actions to props react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to map an action to props however however I'm getting an error:
*TypeError: _this2.props.updateUsername is not a function*

How does one successfully map redux actions to props and call the function successfully? I havnt seen this error pop up in any other stackoverflow question/answers is it a simple mistake? Could it be a wrong setup of redux in .index or .app?

I have tried:
 - importing without using default export
 - having different formats of mapDispatchToProps (eg without using bindactioncreators)
 - fixing typos

- Component:

  ```
  import { updateUsername } from "../../actions/user-actions";
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
  import { Button } from "primereact/button";
  import { Password } from "primereact/password";
  import "./UserLogin.css";
  import { connect } from "react-redux";
  import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

  export class UserLoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { //used to be using states so ill leave these here for now
        username: "", 
        password: "",
        renderTryAgain: false
      };

      this.checkLoginDetails.bind(this.checkLoginDetails);
    }

    async checkLoginDetails() {
      ...
    }

    render() {
      const usernameBox = (
        <InputText
          ...
          value={this.props.username}
          onChange={e => this.props.updateUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
      );

      const passwordBox = (
        <Password
          ...
        />
      );

      const loginButton = (
        <Button
          ...
        />
      );

      return (
        <header className="User-login">
          <p>Dashboard User Login</p>
          <div className="p-grid">
            <div className="p-col">{usernameBox}</div>
            <div className="p-col">{passwordBox}</div>
            <div className="p-col">{loginButton}</div>
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    username: state.username
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(
    {
      updateUsername,
    },
    dispatch,
  )

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(UserLoginPage);
  ```

Reducers:

```
import { UPDATE_USERNAME} from '../actions/user-actions'

export function passReducer(state = "", {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    case true:
      return payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function usernameReducer(state = '', {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_USERNAME:
      return payload.username
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default { passReducer, usernameReducer };
```

- Action:

  ```
  export const UPDATE_USERNAME = 'username:updateUsername'
  export function updateUsername(newUsername){
      return {
          type: UPDATE_USERNAME,
          payload: {
              username: newUsername
          }
      }
  }

  export default {UPDATE_USERNAME, updateUsername}
  ```

Many Thanks

Comment: check your `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: Your action name is updateUsername not onUpdateUsername check your typo.

Comment: Fixed typo, but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Can you check once after updating your constructor as below?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //...
  }
```

Comment: can you update the code, with all the cleared typos and suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use mapDispatchToProps. Instead just wrap all the actions you want to map inside an object and pass them as the second argument to the connect helper method.

Like this `connect(mapStateToProps, { updateUsername })(UserLoginPage)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Faisal, I tried this too however still get the same error!

Comment: @izzyp I've checked the code again and I noticed that you're exporting the actions twice. Try removing the last export statement in the actions file.